# log4net: how to filter appenders?

Tags: log4net

As I know log4net put log record to all of active appenders.
I'd like to have a possibility to output log record to all active but excluding some appenders by criteria (part of name etc)
Is it possible to filter appenders like it is done in NLog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a filter to an appender

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
...
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
    <levelMax value="WARN" />
  </filter>
...
</appender>
```

some filters are:

```
> log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter 
> log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter
> log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter 
> log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter
> log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter 
> log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter
```

See: [Filter Documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/N_log4net_Filter.htm)